# TypeError: end must be None or a string, not KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, runtime-error, keyboardinterrupt

if i press CTRL+C it Errors `TypeError: end must be None or a string, not KeyboardInterrupt`
Why?

### Code:

```
import sys
def erroring(a,b,c):
  print(end=b)
sys.excepthook = erroring
while 1:pass
```

Comment: `b` is an exception object, which cannot be used as the `end=` argument to `print()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.excepthook` needs to be a function that accepts three arguments: the type, the exception object itself, and the traceback.

Like John Gordon said in the comments, `b`, the second argument, will contain the exception itself. The reason it says `TypeError: end must be None or a string, not KeyboardInterrupt` is because there is a type error because `end` must be `None` or type `str`, and you are giving it a `KeyboardInterrupt`. It helps to read the exceptions because they usually tell you the issue.

I would like to elaborate more on his comment though otherwise there would be no point in posting an answer - you should generally not be using `print(end = message)`. Use `print(message, end = "")` - I don't have a source that says this is better, but a) the message is what you're printing and `end` is meant to be the terminator/separator defaulting to newline that goes *between* the content - not the content itself. b) as you see here, `end`, unlike the `print` function in general, can't take any object. You can `print(x)` for any `x` even if it's not a string, but you cannot use `end = x` for non-strings.

So, the easy way to fix this is:

```py
def erroring(a, b, c):
    print(b, end = "")
```

(Why do you want `end = ""` anyway? Also, what exactly are you trying to do?)